# Installing KDE Plasma 4 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kde, kde4

Is it possible to install Plasma 4 in Ubuntu 16.04?

I've had a lot of problems with KDE since I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, and Plasma 4 was great.

I've tried to find some PPA, but I could not find anything that allows me to install the old Plasma in the new Ubuntu version.